# How to pass a method pointer to a struct (in C/C++)?

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers

I have a C++ class which has a pointer representing something like a C interface of this class. Actually everything works well except one thing: I cannot pass method pointer to this struct in MyClass constructor. The example implementation looks like below:

```
//pure C code
typedef int CI_AFunction(CI_Struct*);

typedef struct CI_MyClass //C Interface of MyClass
{
   CI_AFunction* func;
}CI_MyClass;



//C++ code 
class MyClass
{
  private:
      CI_AFunction* _func;
      CI_MyClass* ptrCI_MyClass;

  public:
     MyClass(): _func(**WHAT TO PUT IN HERE TO MAKE IT POINT TO MyFunc?**)
     {
       ptrCI_MyClass= new CI_MyClass;
       ptrCI_MyClass->func=_func;
     }

     int MyFunc(CI_Struct* str)
     {
       // do something
       return 0;
     }

     CI_MyClass* GetCInterface()
     {
        return ptrCI_MyClass;
     }
};


//more or less usage looks somewhat like this:
CI_ptr->func(CI_StructInstancePtr); //in different C file
```

How to solve this? I am not sure it such approach is even possible, however solving it that way would be the most convienient even if not elegant. This "C interface" is supposed only to reveal this one function to C code, therefore I am not trying to make the whole good-programming-practice C API.

EDIT: Thank you all guys for help. Your hints really let me solve the problem. I have created a singleton which for a manager of something isn't a bad approach. Now I have static functions and everything works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @n.m. I don't think it is a duplicate of given post

Comment: Well on the second thought I just don't understand what you are trying to do. C interfaces to C++ classes are not built like that. What you have done is not usable as a C intrerface at all, and it's hard to imagine what it can be used for.

Comment: @n. m. I only need to pass a single function to a C file. That is all. The file is a plugin written in C for a C++ program, and I need to register it. Everything works except passing this function pointer.

Comment: You need to write a standalone (non-member) function and declare it as `extern "C"`. The signature must be compatible with C, i.e. must not use any C++-specific keywords or features. This is the only way to create C interfaces to C++ classes.

Comment: You don't need any of the two pointers that you have in your class. The object knows its own pointer, it's called `this`. It also can call its own member function without any need to store a pointer to such. These two pointers are in fact 100% redundant.

Comment: @n.m. I know, but I don't think that i will be able to pass `this` to a C function and then call it as `void* obj=(void*)PassedThisPtr->AFunction()`

Comment: You should be able to pass `this` to a C function as an opaque pointer. You don't *need* to call your callback as you describe, and in fact *cannot* do that in C code. There is no hidden parameter passing in C, don't even try. You can and should do `AFunction(passedThisPtr)` instead.

Comment: @n.m. I get: Error - invalid type conversion in VC++

Comment: Show your code, preferably in a separate question and after you have searched "how to call a c++ function from c" or some such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointers are incompatible, you might be able to store the pointer but you could not call it
What you want to do is to cast an stdcall to a thiscall, they work differently.
I See 2 possible workarounds here.

1. If MyFunc is marked as `static` it behaves the same as an stdcall, but then u cannot use `this` in the method and you are bound to use `CI_Struct* str` instead.

   when the method is marked as static you can cast it down to a regular c function

   ```
   _func ( (CI_AFunction) &MyClass::MyFunc )
   ```
2. u'll have to 'bridge' between them. The C interface would somehow need to call a function capable of running a call on an object (C++ish).
   Something like

   ```
   int adapter( int (MyClass::*pMethod)(CI_Struct*), MyClass *obj )
   {
       return obj->pMethod(obj->GetCInterface()); /* or 3rd param that is the struct */
   }
   ```

Option 1 seem to be what u'r looking for since you have passed the struct that as I understand should contain all data.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef int CI_AFunction(CI_Struct*);
```

This statement is not creating a `typedef` for a function pointer. if you want to create a `typedef` for function pointer use this format,

```
typedef int (*CI_AFunction)(CI_Struct*);
```

Comment: Indeed, it's creating a typedef for a function type, with `CI_AFunction*` as the pointer type. Why are you suggesting changing the typedef?

Answer (score 1):

`typedef int (MyClass::*ptrType)(CIStruct* str)`

Now

`ptrType realPtr = &MyClass::MyFunc`

i.e., `_func(realPtr)`

Pass realPtr to the constructor

Comment: Error: cannot convert from MyClass::MyFunc' to 'CI_AFunction (__cdecl *)'
1>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible

Comment: Your first typedef is wrong. It must be typedef int (MyClass::*CI_AFunction)(CI_Struct*);. Now you might get unknown class 'MyClass' error. Just remember to forward declare 'MyClass'.

Comment: How does a C++-only member-function pointer help to pass a function pointer to a C interface?

Comment: ^Got the question completely wrong.Thanks for pointing out. Just do a type cast then? What is the issue here.?

Comment: @Prabhu I get an error when trying to do a cast type.

Answer (score 1):

Only non-member or static member functions can be pointed to by regular function pointers.

If your function doesn't need to access (non-static) members of `MyClass`, then you can simply make it static (or make it a non-member).

If it does need to, then you'll need a static "trampoline" function to call the member function on some object. If you can change the C interface, then you could pass an object pointer as an extra argument:

```
typedef int CI_AFunction(CI_Struct*, void* user_data);

struct CI_MyClass
{
    CI_AFunction* func;
    void* user_data;
};
```

Define a static (or non-member) function to interpret that pointer as an object to call the member function on:

```
int MyFunc_wrapper(CI_Struct* s, void* user_data) {
    static_cast<MyClass*>(user_data)->MyFunc(s);
}
```

Then provide a pointer to call it with:

```
ptrCI_MyClass->func=MyFunc_wrapper; // or &MyClass::MyFunc_wrapper for static member
ptrCI_MyClass->user_data = this;
```

If you can't change the C interface to pass arbitrary user data to the callback, then you're rather stuck. You might be able to cobble together one or more global variables to indicate which `MyClass` to use, but it won't be pretty.